# XML-Schema: What is this type restricting `xs:anyType` useful for

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, xsd, jaxb

I have got this xml type definition which I dont understand and which I would like to map to a property of a java bean:

```
<xs:complexType mixed="true" name="SimpleLiteral">      
    <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any maxOccurs="0" minOccurs="0" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I suppose it is best to map this to a `String`-property. But what is that typedefinition useful for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value space of the type itself would be equivalent to that of the simple type **xs:string** in my understanding as well unless I'm missing something. I'd see the difference in terms of the type system and hierarchy.

It is different from, say, the simple type **xs:string** in the sense that it is a complex type, and that it can, as such, be derived by extension to create subtypes that have element tags and/or attributes. This can have an impact in languages consuming XML-Schema-validated instances, such as XQuery.

I am not saying this is necessarily the intent of the above declaration, but this is in any case something that can be done:

```
<xs:complexType name="stringWithTags">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
        <xs:extension base="SimpleLiteral">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="some-tag" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Ah, that would be a possible usecase. I think extending that type to add elements should not be possible due to `maxOccurs="0"`. But if I look at the complete xsd there are indeed derived types that add additional attributes. Thanks!

Comment: The XML Schema type system does not strictly enforce that the value space of a subtype is a subset of that of its supertype. Derivation by extension is the counterexample, as it is possible to add elements and attributes to the base type.